# Issue Picking Image From Kitkat Gallery

Tags: android, gallery, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using following code which is working perfectly on every Lollipop, Marshmallow, etc.. devices but on KitKat which is bit older, i am getting following crash, which seems like path is invalid or null that is causing this crash.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131294, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/3965 (has extras) }} to activity {com.yospace.b4umobile/com.yospace.b4umobile.NonLogedInScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3641)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3684)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:166)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.yospace.b4umobile.fragments.Signup.getResizedBitmap(Signup.java:934)
       at com.yospace.b4umobile.fragments.Signup.onSelectFromGalleryResult(Signup.java:873)
       at com.yospace.b4umobile.fragments.Signup.onActivityResult(Signup.java:752)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:165)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5634)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3637)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3684)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:166)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

**Here is my code:**

```
private void galleryIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_GALLERY_CODE);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {

                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());


                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                        selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                if (filePath == null)
                    setLolliPopPath(data);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

             /*   storeImage(bm, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

                filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myAppDir/" + FILE_NAME;*/
            }
        }

        //ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
if(bm!=null)
        profile_img.setImageBitmap(getResizedBitmap(bm, 250));
       else
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Issue with your device. Fail to access gallery",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
private void setLolliPopPath(Intent data) {

        String wholeID="";
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
            wholeID=getUriPreKitkat(selectedImage);
        }else {
            wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(selectedImage);

        }

        // Split at colon, use second item in the array
        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

        String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        // where id is equal to
        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().
                query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);


        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
        cursor.close();

    }
```

Device Details:
[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "Kitkat Gallery", and your code has little to do with a "gallery".

There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across ~10,000 device models, themselves spanning hundreds of manufacturers and (unfortunately) a dozen or so versions of Android. Hundreds of different apps supporting `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` will ship pre-installed on those devices, and hundreds (if not thousands) more are available to be installed by users from the Play Store and other app distribution channels.

You assume that every `Uri` delivered to `onActivityResult()` is known to the `MediaStore`. In reality, there is no requirement for the `Uri` delivered to `onActivityResult()` have anything to do with the `MediaStore`.

For example, I can write an app that supports `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and returns a `Uri` to an image that my app serves up via `FileProvider`, where that image is stored in my app's portion of internal storage. `MediaStore` will know nothing about this image. Nor will `DocumentsContract`.

**The `Uri` is an opaque handle, and you should be making no assumptions whatsoever about where that `Uri` comes from**.

Use `ContentResolver`, `openInputStream()`, and `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` to get a `Bitmap` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Or, better yet, use an image-loading library (e.g., Glide, Picasso), as they will do that work on a background thread, whereas your code is freezing the UI while you do all this I/O.